# Where Case statement using separate field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having difficulty getting the where clause in this SQL statement to return  the appropriate records. Basically we have a table that lists all the dates within a year and related information. The primary key is a converted `varchar(8)` into a `YYYYMMDD` format [i.e. do a `convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112)` to see the format return I am talking about]. This is my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimDate
WHERE datekey = 
(
  CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
      SELECT datekey 
      from dimdate 
      where 
        datekey = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
    ) = 2 
    THEN 
      convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
    WHEN 
    (
      SELECT datekey 
      from dimdate 
      where 
        datekey = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
    ) = 1 
    THEN 
      convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-2,getdate()), 112)
    ELSE '20190115' 
  END
)
/*
datekey = (CASE [DayOfWeek]
WHEN 1 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
WHEN 2 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-4,getdate()), 112)
ELSE '20190109' END)
-- */
--convert(varchar(8), dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
```

It always defaults to the `ELSE` portion. I have included several of the various attempts (commented out) I have used and gotten the results from. And yes, I have manually checked the table for data to make sure it exists. The codes' goal is that if today is Sunday or Monday, then I need to get the record(s) last Friday. The Else statement is hard-coded as it is now because otherwise I get no records returned.

**I was able to get both working. To answer some of the comments below - yes part of the query I posted had an incorrect field in the select statement. That was my error in modifying it for the forum. That still would not have worked. Am posting both the working version and another using the datepart as suggested in what I marked as answer:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimDate
WHERE datekey = 
Case DATEPART(dw, getdate())
    WHEN 1 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
    WHEN 2 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-4,getdate()), 112)
ELSE convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
END

SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimDate
WHERE datekey = 
    (CASE (SELECT [DayOfWeek] FROM DimDate WHERE datekey = 
convert(varchar, getdate(), 112))
        WHEN 1 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
        WHEN 2 THEN convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-4,getdate()), 112)
        ELSE '20190109'
    END)
```

As a final note, this needs to be inline as it is used in a bigger query returning moderate summation sets which is why I am not declaring variables and such. Thank you all again for your input and help!!

Comment: I don't understand your subqueries. `SELECT datekey 
      from dimdate 
      where 
        datekey = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)` will just return `convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)` or `NULL`, neither of which can ever be equal to `1` or `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `CASE` statement the way comparing for the day of the week is wrong. You should make use of the `DATEPART(DW, date)` to get the day of the week, but in the provided SQL statement you comparing the two string which would either return `TRUE` OR `FALSE`.

Your SQL statement should be restructured as

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimDate
WHERE datekey = 
(
  CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
      SELECT DATEPART(DW, getdate())
    ) = 2 
    THEN 
      convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()), 112)
    WHEN 
    (
      SELECT DATEPART(DW, getdate())
    ) = 1 
    THEN 
      convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-2,getdate()), 112)
    ELSE '20190115' 
  END
)
```

Personally, I'd take the below approach to streamline the SQL statement since the current date would be static and it'd improve performance of the statement as the data set gets larger.

```
DECLARE @dow INT = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())
DECLARE @daysSinceLastFriday INT = CASE 
                                    WHEN 
                                        @dow=2
                                    THEN -3
                                    WHEN 
                                        @dow=1
                                    THEN -2
                                    ELSE
                                        0       -- Assign with the suitable default day of the week 
                                    END;

DECLARE @lastFriday VARCHAR(8) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd,@daysSinceLastFriday,GETDATE()), 112)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimDate
    WHERE datekey = @lastFriday
```

Comment: All of the columns (datekey, dayofweek) are actual fields in the DimDate table (which is why they are surrounded by []). I was trying to use the existing data rather than functions. And no, I did not set this up thankfully I happen to just be the new....owner.  However it may very well be better to get the day of week from the date and go that route. Will try and post back or close. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to actually get both to work. Just had to step back a bit and look at it.